# multiple short videos on webpage

Tags: performance, video, filesize

A friend and I are launching an online art gallery. The first artist we have exhibiting has a series of videos and stills I was hoping to have all on one page, auto playing and looping.

I have the layout all set, videos scaled down to what i thought was a manageable size, everything looks good locally (-__-) but now upon uploading files, are slow and stuttering. This doesn't really surprise me, I know videos are big files. But i was hoping someone would have some insights about getting these 6 videos to load smoothly.

Currently all videos are in the 35-90 MB range.

Would it be best to try and call each video to load upon scroll? How do I do that? Is this a hopeless dream for all these videos to autoplay without video control chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Playing multiple videos on a single page will be sensitive to bandwidth and browser/device processing variations.

The bandwidth part is probably obvious - the processing part is because the device has to decode and playback each video separately, and video processing is quite compute heavy.

Many devices also have optimised HW accelerated video pipelines - essentially special HW that reduces the processing overload with video playback. This will quite likely not be set up for, or optimised for, playing back multiple videos.

One approach to the problem you have is to combine all the videos into a single video on the server side - if you can find a display format that you are happy with for this approach it means you only have to then stream and playback a single video on the device.